# Error shown in Python - TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow() :'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I just started python today..  Spent hours on codeacademy and learnt quite a bit so I thought I'd make my own program to square the ages of a person and their sibling. Very basic just a starter. Pretty useless actually just wanted to see what I can do.  I keep getting this TypeError mentioned in the title. Here's my code :

```
a=raw_input(''enter age'') 
b=raw_input(''sibling's age'') 
Square=a**2 + b**2 + 2ab
If square <160:
    Print 'really young people' 
Else:
    Print 'square of sum >160'
```

Please help
Thanks!!

Comment: Start by learning Python 3, not 2.

Comment: Even before the type problems, this code is full of syntax errors. You need to post code you actually ran.

Comment: Alright but will this work in python 3?

Comment: @user2357112 this is the code I ran... It works just fine till the mathematical part

Comment: @KarlStark: No it's not. If you tried to run this code, you would get a SyntaxError instead of a TypeError. This code is different from the code you actually ran on every single line, as every single line has a syntax problem that would have aborted compilation with a SyntaxError before the TypeError could occur.

Comment: @KarlStark I really want to know, what made you type this code here instead of copy pasting the actual code you ran? A lot of people do this and I can't understand the motivation.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, if you're just starting, you ***really*** should be learning Python 3, not 2.

The code you posted has many issues. Here's a line-by-line breakdown, with corrections in Python 3:

```
a=raw_input(''enter age'') 
b=raw_input(''sibling's age'')
```

You need to use either single quotes `'` or double quotes `"`, but not two single quotes to define strings. Try:

```
a = int(input("Enter age"))
b = int(input("Sibling's age"))
```

There is no `raw_input()` in Python 3, it's just [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). This function also returns a string, so if you want to do math on it you need to call [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to turn the result into an integer.

```
Square=a**2 + b**2 + 2ab
```

As long as `a` and `b` are ints, the first two parts of the expression are fine, but you need to remember that all operations in Python are explicit, so you'll need to fix the last part like so:

```
Square = a**2 + b**2 + 2*a*b
```

Now for the last part:

```
If square <160:
    Print 'really young people' 
Else:
    Print 'square of sum >160'
```

Python is case-sensitive. Since you used `Square` above, you'll need to use the same capitalization down here. Likewise, builtin keywords and functions are all in lowercase (`if`, `else`, `print()`, etc.). Finally, in Python 3 [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function, not a statement, so you'll need parentheses `( )` around your arguments:

```
if Square < 160:
    print("Really young people")
else:
    print("square of sum > 160")
```

---

So, here's your complete Python 3 code:

```
a = int(input("Enter age"))
b = int(input("Sibling's age"))
Square = a**2 + b**2 + 2*a*b
if Square < 160:
    print("Really young people")
else:
    print("square of sum > 160")
```

Comment: While learning Python 3 would be a good move, I think mixing syntax corrections and Python 2->3 conversions confuses the issue.

Comment: @user2357112 perhaps, but since it's the OP's first day learning Python, I want to get them on the right track as quickly as possible.